# Getting error: The content of element type "web-app" must match,

Tags: servlets, web.xml

When I build my project in Eclipse Helios Service Release 2, I get an error in my `web.xml`. Please suggest what I have to do for this. In my project I am using DTD 2.2. The error is below.

> The content of element type "web-app" must match "(icon?,display-
>    name?,description?,distributable?,context-param*,servlet*,servlet-mapping*,session-config?,mime-
>    mapping*,welcome-file-list?,error-page*,taglib*,resource-ref*,security-constraint*,login-config?,security-
>    role*,env-entry*,ejb-ref*)".

Comment: We can't tell you what's wrong with your `web.xml` unless you actually show it to us.

Answer (score 79):

The error message tells you in detail in what order the elements are supposed to be placed and how many of them are allowed. In other words, the ordering or amount of the elements inside the `<web-app>` of your `web.xml` is incorrect. For example, as per the error message, `<servlet>` needs to go *before* `<servlet-mapping>`. The `?` suffix means that there may be *zero or one* of them. The `*` suffix means that there may be *zero or many* of them.

So, the example below is **invalid**:

```
<servlet>...</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>...</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>...</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>...</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>...</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>...</servlet-mapping>
```

While the example below is **valid**:

```
<servlet>...</servlet>
<servlet>...</servlet>
<servlet>...</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>...</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>...</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>...</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thx, the `<servlet>`, `<servlet-mapping>` order was my problem!

Comment: Thanks. I had a totally different error but knowing that the errors are saying that my tags (?) are not in the proper order is very helpful.

Comment: I had a similar error. my Filters were before Context Params, changed back the order and this helped. Thanks

Comment: try configuring using design view instead of source view in eclipse. It will work

Answer (score 4):

If anyone's interested I received the same exception for error-page.  This node needs to go after servlet, but before servlet-mapping.

Comment: I had a similar problem where `<welcome-file-list>` needed to come after `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>`

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue when I integrate `spring` to `struts2` in `Eclipse`. After some testing, I found it's the problem of tag's order in `web.xml` file. The following file has the error

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>struts.devMode</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

If I changed the order to

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>struts.devMode</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The error will be eliminated.

Hope this will be helpful to the people who encounter the same problem.