# gwt.xml error: Content of element type module must match

Tags: gwt

I have a small GWT java program that has been running on google apps engine for about a year now.  I recently made some changes to it, and then before I could deploy it had to update the JRE to 7.1.  Once I did that, I am getting the following error on my gwt.xml file:

```
The content of element type "module" must match "(inherits|source|public|super-source|entry-point|stylesheet|script|servlet|replace-with|
generate-with|define-property|extend-property|set-property|set-property-fallback|clear-configuration-property|define-configuration-
property|extend-configuration-property|set-configuration-property|property-provider|define-linker|add-linker|collapse-all-properties|collapse-property)*".
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712906/getting-error-the-content-of-element-type-web-app-must-match) question which explained to me what the error meant, and I saw that my source elements were after my entry point element.  I moved them around to match the order in the error message, but the error persists.  Any thoughts?

Here is my gwt.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 When updating your version of GWT, you should also update this DTD reference,
 so that your app can take advantage of the latest GWT module capabilities.
-->
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.0//EN"
"http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='helpdesktest'>

<!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.xml.XML'/>
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.logging.Logging'/>
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.http.HTTP'/>

<!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
<!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
<!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

<!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

<!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
<source path='client'/>
<source path='shared'/>

<!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
<entry-point class='com.google.gwt.HelpDeskTest.client.HelpDeskTest'/>


<!-- Set logging parameters -->
<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="SEVERE"/> #change default log level
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="FALSE"/> #set to FALSE to disable logging
<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="DISABLED"/> #to disable set to DISABLED
<set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED"/> 
<set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler" value="DISABLED"/> 

</module>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<module>` doesn't accept text content, yet you have those `#change default log level` bits in your file.

Convert them to XML comments (`<!-- change default log leve -->`) or remove them.

---

BTW, the order of the elements doesn't matter wrt XML validation (it matters in what they mean though; some things sometimes have to be processed for others because one overrides the other)

Comment: Thank you.  I deleted the # sign and everything after it on those three lines and I'm still getting the error.  I tried commenting out different sections of the xml file to see if that made a difference and it didn't.  Hmmm....

Comment: So due to some other errors I ended up doing a fresh install of Eclipse and GWT and that error went away.  So I don't know what that was all about.  :/